# Continuous "recursive iteration"

Tags: functions, definite-integrals, continuity

When defining functions over a countable set (usually $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$) they are often defined recursively, e.g. factorial is often defined as.

$$f(0)=1, f(n)=n\cdot f(n-1)$$

I was wondering if the same can be done continuously, and as most transfers from discreet to continuous I expect this to take an integral form of some sort. Is the following a valid definition for a function then?

$$f(x)=1, 0\leq x\leq 1,\quad f(x)=\int_0^{x-1}f(x)\enspace \text{otherwise}$$

so that up to $f(2)$ we are integrating the constant function defined before, and starting from $x>2$ we add to the integrating the result of the previous integration. It seems valid but leaves me at unease for some reason...

Comment: Slightly relevant: [the Gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html)

Comment: Also slightly relevant: if the discrete recurrence is $u(n) = f(u(n-1))$ then an analogous differential equation would be $u' = f(u)$, which you could perhaps solve to get a "continuous recurrence".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. What you have is a solution to a delay differential equation. The solutions to those often involve integrals.