# Tell whether module of root of such polynomial is smaller than 1

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let's consider such polynomial:
$$ W_n(z)=\sum_{k=1}^n kz^{k-1} $$
Tell whether this statement is true for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$W_n(z)=0 \Rightarrow |z|<1$$

Here is what I have evaluated:

It is obvious that $z$ can't be a real number bigger or equal to $0$. 
Also, if $n$ is even, then $z$ can't be a real number smaller than $-1$, because if it was, we would have:
$$W_n(z)=\sum_{k=1}^n kz^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\Big((2k+1)z^{2k}+2kz^{2k-1}\Big)=\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}z^{2k-1}\Big(2kz+2k+z\Big)$$
Both $z^{2k-1}$ and $2kz+2k+z$ are smaller than $-1$ so each term of the last sum is bigger than $1$ so the final sum is bigger than $0$.

Comment: Couldn't find a way of contacting you! I asked your question... it got some responses. 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2765086/writing-the-recursive-as-explicit

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't been answering your post, but after my question being discarded, I didn't have enough points to comment other people posts. I saw the post and the answers. They are interesting but I still didn't make any valuable evaluations. I asked my math professor from university and he is going to search something in the literature after trying to solve this problem and failing himself. Once he gives me some response I'm going to post it

Answer (score 1):

$W_n$ is the derivative of $P_n(z):= \sum_{k=0}^nz^k$, the roots of which are the $n+1$-th roots of unity (with the exception of $1$). By Gauss-Lucas theorem, the roots of $W_n$ lie in the convex hull of the roots of $P_n$. Besides, the roots of $P_n$ are all distinct, thus have multiplicity $1$ (so they are not roots of $W_n$). Therefore, the roots of $W_n$ lie stricly inside the unit disk, i.e. they have modules $<1$.